# Why doesn't my balance bought on Coinbase show up on Blockchain.info?

Tags: coinbase.com

I've been trying out different Bitcoin services and I've run into a bit of a conundrum with Coinbase. I purchased a small amount of Bitcoin several days ago and this morning, the transaction was marked as complete and showed up in my balance. However, the listed address under `Account Settings > Bitcoin Addresses` has no history and no BTC associated with it when viewed on `blockchain.info`.

Is this expected behaviour? The initial purchase stated that the bitcoins would arrive by the end of the day today. Does this mean that the "completed" transaction is not in fact complete yet and I'm still waiting on Coinbase? I've emailed Coinbase about this matter as well and will update this post in any case. Just figured I might get a faster response from more experienced users here.

EDIT: Just found [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17113/bitcoin-address-does-not-show-transaction-balance-from-coinbase-purchase?rq=1) and I suspect that it serves as a sufficient answer to my question. If anyone else has any comments to add, please do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is expected behavior, Coinbase is not a full wallet and that means the funds under addresses it shows you are completely irrelevant. When you withdraw to an address, Coinbase will send the amount specified.